# Glassfish connection from Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

Connecting to Glassfish from ASADMIN terminal works fine but whenever I try to connect to Glassfish from Netbeans I get this error

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
objc[86481]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x107a3f4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x108aa94e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Feb 15, 2017 12:43:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Feb 15, 2017 12:43:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Feb 15, 2017 12:43:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Feb 15, 2017 12:43:19 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@7ff366d0 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (31,891ms), startup services(594ms), total(32,485ms)
Severe:   Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:237)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:374)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Server shutdown initiated
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@30a7c98f as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@7e1f584d.
Info:   Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@30a7c98f from service registry.
Info:   FileMonitoring shutdown
Completed shutdown of Log manager service
Info:   Shutdown procedure finished
```

Sometimes I get this error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
objc[86884]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10f98b4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1119fe4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Feb 15, 2017 12:49:41 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFO: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
Feb 15, 2017 12:49:41 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Feb 15, 2017 12:49:41 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Feb 15, 2017 12:49:41 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@583c0b34 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
Info:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Info:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Info:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Info:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Info:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 31ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Warning:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Info:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (32,118ms), startup services(724ms), total(32,842ms)
Info:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Info:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Info:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@2822c6ff as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@60d1b21f.
Info:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://172.18.76.116:8686/jndi/rmi://172.18.76.116:8686/jmxrmi
```

After this phase, it should normally say Grizzly framework started but it gets stuck here for a while and then pops up an error asking me to check Admin username and password or to check server logs. I have tried empty username and password field as well as adding "admin" in username and empty password as well as adding both username and password but it still gives same error.

I am currently using Macbook pro for this and I keep getting this error whenever I try to connect using Netbeans while connecting with ASADMIN works.

I have tried re-installing everything from scratch but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first exception is a port binding issue. It means that there is already something running (probably another GlassFish instance).

The second issue you're having isn't a problem with GlassFish per se, but almost certainly a problem with the `.gfclient` which you'll find stored in your user's home directory (on Mac, I believe that's something like /Users/yourName/.gfclient)

Try removing .gfclient totally, so any cached user/password credentials are removed. You may also need to remove and re-add the GlassFish server to Netbeans.

Comment: Thank you bro, that fixed the problem :D I did as you said and restarted the System and re-opened netbeans then it worked :D